# Can I share IIS virtual directory among multiple web servers without impacting performance

Tags: iis-7

I am hosting a web application on a scaled environment of N servers (Web01, Web02, ... , Web0N) and I have 2 options for deployment:

1. Deploy binaries to each server.
2. Deploy binaries to one server (let's say Web01) and share them with other servers.

The only benefit from option 2 is to ensure consistency among servers and avoid deploying different binaries on any of the servers.

However, I assume this creates I/O and Network bottlenecks on server Web01 as all servers access the same DISK through NETWORK to load binaries and configurations.

**My Questions Are:**

- Can anybody confirm or contradict my assumption?
- Is there a way to apply a POC and compare the results in numbers?

Comment: In a real world web farm, it is common to see option 1. Disk space is not a problem usually. The problem of option 2 is the extra network bandwidth consumption to query files from the file share (Web01 in your case), and the unnecessary delay of SMB packets. In edge cases it can exhaust available ports and lead to contention.

Comment: @LexLi I see you agree with my concern around option 2 from extra network traffic perspective. Just assuring that I didn't go for option 2 to save disk space. but to avoid deploying different binaries to different servers (by mistake)